# Polymer 2 - can't access #document-fragment for unit tests

Tags: polymer-2.x

I'm trying to access a sub-component's local DOM for unit tests, but all I'm seeing in the dev console is #document-fragment. Anyone know a way around that?

[image]

Comment: did you find anything relevant?